# React Native: <Text> won't render if placed inside <TouchableHighlight>

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the following code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native'),

{
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Component,
  NavigatorIOS
} = React,

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 36,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderColor: '#48BBEC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 80
  }
})

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    /*<TouchableHighlight
      style={styles.button}
      underlayColor='#99d9f4'>*/
      <Text style={styles.text}>Login with Google</Text>
    /*</TouchableHighlight>*/
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Login
```

The `<Text>` Login gets rendered only when the surrounding `<TouchableHighlight>` is commented out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, other than the components (jsx tags), feels just like react to me. Anything in particular you find different from react?

Comment: This is weird. It works for me, but only if I add TouchableHighlight to the things I'm importing from React. But if that's not there then I get the red screen of death...

Comment: Wow - I forgot to import TouchableHighlight, but React didn't show me the red screen so I never even bothered to check if I'd imported it. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import 'TouchableHighlight'.
Add TouchableHighlight to your list of requires.

```
var React = require('react-native'),

{
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Component,
  NavigatorIOS,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React,
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the  tag, you have to import it in the destructuring assignment block just like `Text` and `View`.